# Overriding dependencies on npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working on an application that I inherited. Upon doing an `npm install`, initially I got various messages that packages have been either deprecated or they were soon to be end of life. So I started upgrading some of the packages and now I'm running into some dependency issues. I don't really know how to approach this situation, but below is the `package.json`and also the output of the `npm install`. Any advice would be appreciated.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "guide-front-end",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "graphqltest": "mocha --require babel-core/register server_src/graphql/tests/test.spec.js --reporter spec",
    "dockerstart": "node dist/app.js",
    "dockerstart-noangular": "node dist/app --noangular",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "prodbuild": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run prodbuild && npm run babel-build",
    "build-graphql": "babel ./server_src -s -d ./dist --copy-files",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "ng-build": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "babel-build": "babel ./server_src -d ./dist -s --copy-files --ignore spec.js,testharness.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.2",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-expressions": "^0.3.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "apollo-angular": "0.13.0",
    "apollo-client": "1.8.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-url-rewrite": "^1.0.2",
    "express-winston": "^2.3.0",
    "graphql": "^0.10.5",
    "graphql-anywhere": "^2.2.0",
    "graphql-server-core": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-server-express": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^0.10.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "iterall": "^1.0.3",
    "jszip": "^2.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "request-digest": "^1.0.13",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "trim-character": "^2.0.1",
    "tsickle": "^0.21.6",
    "tsutils": "^1.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "winston": "^2.3.1",
    "winston-loggly": "^1.3.1",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.31",
    "@types/graphql": "^0.8.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "graphql-tester": "0.0.5",
    "graphql-typings": "0.0.1-beta-2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
}
```

**npm install output**

```
$ npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @apollo/cache-control-types@1.0.2
npm WARN Found: graphql@0.10.5
npm WARN node_modules/graphql
npm WARN   graphql@"^0.10.5" from the root project
npm WARN   8 more (@graphql-typed-document-node/core, apollo-client, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer graphql@"14.x || 15.x || 16.x" from @apollo/cache-control-types@1.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/@apollo/cache-control-types
npm WARN   @apollo/cache-control-types@"^1.0.2" from @apollo/server@4.3.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@apollo/server
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: graphql@16.6.0
npm WARN node_modules/graphql
npm WARN   peer graphql@"14.x || 15.x || 16.x" from @apollo/cache-control-types@1.0.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@apollo/cache-control-types
npm WARN     @apollo/cache-control-types@"^1.0.2" from @apollo/server@4.3.2
npm WARN     node_modules/@apollo/server
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @apollo/server@4.3.2
npm ERR! Found: graphql@0.10.5
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^0.10.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @graphql-typed-document-node/core@3.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@graphql-typed-document-node/core
npm ERR!     @graphql-typed-document-node/core@"^3.1.1" from @graphql-tools/utils@9.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@graphql-tools/utils
npm ERR!       @graphql-tools/utils@"9.2.0" from @graphql-tools/merge@8.3.17
npm ERR!       node_modules/@graphql-tools/merge
npm ERR!         @graphql-tools/merge@"8.3.17" from @graphql-tools/schema@9.0.15
npm ERR!         node_modules/@graphql-tools/schema
npm ERR!       1 more (@graphql-tools/schema)
npm ERR!   7 more (apollo-client, graphql-tag, apollo-server-core, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^16.6.0" from @apollo/server@4.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@apollo/server
npm ERR!   @apollo/server@"^4.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: graphql@16.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^16.6.0" from @apollo/server@4.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/server
npm ERR!     @apollo/server@"^4.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\isandozi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-04T21_15_50_537Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\isandozi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-04T21_15_50_537Z-debug-0.log
```